# I want to show the Post title, Post Featured Image, Post Exrept and Post full Content (Post Body), Everything is showing except full post content

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have 2 search form where user can search the celebrity name, in the result, Post Title, Post Featured Image, Post Exrept and Post full content shows. Everything is okay to show but full post content is not showing.
Below is my code:

```
// Function to get complete post content
function get_celebrity_post_content($post) {
  ob_start();
  ?>
  <div>
    <h2><?php echo get_the_title($post); ?></h2>
    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'); ?>
    <p><strong>Excerpt:</strong> <?php echo get_the_excerpt($post); ?></p>
    <div><?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?></div>
  </div>
  <?php
  $content = ob_get_clean();

  return $content;
}
```

Correction of code to show the full post content.

Comment: Have you checked if `$post->post_content` contains the expected data? What is the context in which this function executes? (Wondering if that is perhaps before the usual `the_content` filter callbacks have been added.)